# how to access dropdown options with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can select "external" option but I can't select "internal" option again! What should I do?
When I select "external" the first time it works correctly, but when I select "internal" its value changes to "external".

```
<p class="list2">
    <label for="list2">choose 1</label>
    <select name="list2" id="list2">
      <option>Internal</option>
      <option>External</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p class="list3">
    <label for="list3">Internal</label>
    <select name="list3" id="list3">
      <option>Internal 1</option>
      <option>Internal 2</option>
      <option>Internal 3</option>
      <option>Internal 4</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p class="list4" style="display: none;">
    <label for="list4">External</label>
    <select name="list4" id="list4">
      <option selected>External 1</option>
      <option>External 2</option>
      <option>External 3</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

and this is my script :

```
(function(){
  var whichSelected = function(){

    $('#list2').change(function() {
      $('#list2 option:selected').each(function() {

        if($(this).text('Internal')){

          $('.list4').css({
            display: 'none',
          });
          $('.list3').css({
            display: 'block',
          });
        }

        if($(this).text('External')){

          $('.list4').css({
            display: 'block',
          });

          $('.list3').css({
            display: 'none',
          });
        }

      });
    });
  },
  init = function(){
    whichSelected();
  };

  $(init);

})();
```

You can watch demo from here : http://jsbin.com/qiwif/2/edit

Comment: For starters, you probably want to replace `$(this).text('Internal')` with `$(this).text() === 'Internal'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).text('Internal')` and `$(this).text('External')` will be truthy, since they are setting the text values.

Use `$(this).text() === 'Internal'` and `$(this).text() === 'External'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the jQuery `text()` function incorrectly.

Calling `text()` without any parameters retrieves the value of the element.

Calling the `text('Internal')` function with a parameter sets the text value of the element.

You should change to use the following lines of code:

```
if($(this).text() == 'Internal'){

if($(this).text() == 'External'){
```

Here is the updated jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/bakoweke/1/edit